# how to pause a backgroundworker thread in case of exception and resume it if exception occurs

Tags: c#, windows

im using following code to send sms to all the students in the database

```
private void btnsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            c.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (!bgw.IsBusy)
        {
            bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
    private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
            {
                using (var sp = new SerialPort(cbcomport.Text))
                {
                    sp.Open();
                    sp.WriteLine("AT" + Environment.NewLine);
                    sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + Environment.NewLine);
                    sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=\"" + dt.Rows[i]["PhoneNo"] + "\"" + Environment.NewLine);
                    sp.WriteLine(tbsms.Text + (char)26);
                    if (sp.BytesToRead > 0)
                    {
                        tbsentto.Text = i + 1 + " of " + dt.Rows.Count;
                    }
                }
            });
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
    private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            c.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

my question is: during sms is being sent to the students if an exception occurs e.g The port 'COM5' does not exist. i want to display the same system message to the user with buttons retry and cancel. if having resolved the problem. i.e having plugged in the device user presses retry button i want to resume the thread from the same point and if user presses cancel button i want to stop the paused thread.

Comment: This can't work, you don't know exactly where it bombed.  Detect the exception by checking e.Error in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler.  Just create a new instance of the bgw and start it again.

Comment: @HansPassant: Why not? It's impractical to resume from the exact *statement* that bombed, but pause/resuming with iteration-level precision is not hard to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
private void btnsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            c.Enabled = false;
        }
        if (!bgw.IsBusy)
        {
            bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
    private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if ((bgw.CancellationPending == true))
            {

                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                    using (var sp = new SerialPort(cbcomport.Text))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            sp.Open();
                            sp.WriteLine("AT" + Environment.NewLine);
                            sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + Environment.NewLine);
                            sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=\"" + dt.Rows[i]["PhoneNo"] + "\"" + Environment.NewLine);
                            sp.WriteLine(tbsms.Text + (char)26);
                            if (sp.BytesToRead > 0)
                            {
                                tbsentto.Text = i + 1 + " of " + dt.Rows.Count;
                            }
                            Thread.Sleep(5000);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            if (MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Retry)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    sp.Open();
                                    sp.WriteLine("AT" + Environment.NewLine);
                                    sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + Environment.NewLine);
                                    sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=\"" + dt.Rows[i]["PhoneNo"] + "\"" + Environment.NewLine);
                                    sp.WriteLine(tbsms.Text + (char)26);
                                    if (sp.BytesToRead > 0)
                                    {
                                        tbsentto.Text = i + 1 + " of " + dt.Rows.Count;
                                    }
                                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex2)
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show(ex2.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                    bgw.CancelAsync();

                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                bgw.CancelAsync();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            c.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For such a scheme, the general idea is that you need to:

- Catch an exception that may be thrown from the worker (but **only** exceptions that you know you can handle; catching all exceptions is **evil**!)
- Notify the UI thread to prompt the user
- Pause executing until the UI thread has received input
- Abort execution if the input indicates so

For the last two items, use a waitable object such as an `AutoResetEvent` and a state variable (even a `bool` will do as a minimum) that indicates if the task should be aborted. These variables must be accessible both from the UI thread and from the worker:

```
AutoResetEvent pauseEvent(false);
bool shouldAbort;
```

The worker's code then becomes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    try
    {
        // your existing code goes here
    }
    catch (SomeException ex) // do not catch all exceptions!
    {
        BeginInvoke(...);     // tell the UI thread something bad happened
        pauseEvent.WaitOne(); // and block the worker until user gives input
        if (shouldAbort)
        {
            // cleanup any other resources if required and then
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In the `BeginInvoke` line, you should call some method that displays an appropriate message to the user and requests instructions. `BeginInvoke` will return immediately and the worker will block indefinitely on the `AutoResetEvent` by calling `pauseEvent.WaitOne`.

The UI method should query the user and after a response has been received it should signal `pauseEvent` with

```
pauseEvent.Set();
```

This will unblock the worker and allow it to resume execution. Due to the structure of the code, this means it will continue with the next iteration of the loop. If you want to make the worker abort instead, set `shouldAbort` to `true` *before* signalling `pauseEvent`.

You can also make the code retry the iteration that threw the exception (instead of skipping it and continuing with the next) if you decrement `i` inside the `catch` block.

Comment: thanks alot. im sorry for being away for some business. im trying to act as directed by you but it would have been better if you had done it using my coding throughly.

Comment: Jon it is very difficult to follow your above mentioned methode to solve my problem. had you used my all coding in your example I may have got benefit from your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You have to you use `sync` objects between threads.
Look  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx) especially in `wait handlers` section.